# Password Reset Email Not Being Sent in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

First of all, I'd just like to clarify that I've looked at all the other questions in regard to this on Stack Overflow and I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

So, the issue I'm having is that I'm not receiving a password reset email on my site, even though everything indicates that the email has been sent. I say this because I get the confirmation on my screen that the email has been sent and I also get the email displayed in the console (see below).

[image]

Here are my email settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = "localhost"
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_ADDRESS")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASSWORD")
```

Here are my password reset URLs:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from accounts.views import change_password
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    password_reset,
    password_reset_done,
    password_reset_confirm,
    password_reset_complete)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', password_reset, name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done,
        name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
        password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^complete/$', password_reset_complete,
        name='password_reset_complete'),
    url(r'^change-password/$', change_password, name='change_password'),
]
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You specified as `EMAIL_BACKEND`:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
```

This is a [*Console backend* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#console-backend), so it does not send an email, but prints the email to the console. This can for example be used for testing purposes.

You can specify as backend for example the [*SMTP backend* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#smtp-backend):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
```